# Django Filter Default Date

Tags: django, django-filter

Unfortunately I can't wrap my head around how to set a default value for a Date Filter, as described in some other posts it should be possible to set it in the init function, but to no avail:

filters.py:

```
class LoaderErrorFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Product.objects.all(), label='Product*')
    operator = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="operator", lookup_expr='contains', label='Operator')
    load_from = django_filters.DateFilter(label='From*')
    load_to = django_filters.DateFilter(label='To*')
    error = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="error", lookup_expr='contains', label='Error')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoaderErrorFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.initial['load_from'] = datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1)
        self.form.initial['load_to'] = datetime.datetime.today()
        if self.data == {}:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.none()
```

The queryset will be filled after the user makes a selection since there are different models affected depending on the choices.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The default values are definitely not propagated to the view, I just get "None" (tried to set one for the char field also to no avail)

Comment: Seems like this is not possible easily anymore (which is a real shame if this is the case as it is not helping the user experience...) https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tips.html#using-initial-values-as-defaults --> tried the workaround but sill no luck